# How to be more productive with CloudFormation?

Tags: deployment, aws

When using Terraform instead of Cloudformation on AWS, I usually get immediate feedback on the terminal, which makes the work very productive.

With CloudFormation, however, I tend to edit the file in my computer, upload it to Cloudformation console on AWS, and keep watching until I get an error/success. Even using CI/CD is not much of an advantage, as the result is usually ROLLBACK_COMPLETE, and I have to go to the console to see what went wrong.

I'm I following the right workflow for Cloudformation? Should I be doing things differently?

Comment: Given that you're clearly happy using the command-line, *why* are you using the console for CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [AWS CLI for CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/index.html#cli-aws-cloudformation) from the terminal would be definitely quicker than clicking around in the AWS Console. Having said that, on occasions, I find it easier and quicker to go to the AWS Console to examine CF events than using the command line.